# Python update rcParams unexpected behavior

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to increase the overall fontsize for a plot and then reset it to the default value. If I increase the fontsize via `plt.rcParams.update()` and decrease it also via `plt.rcParams.update()`, everything works well. However, if I reset the parameters via `plt.rcParams = plt.rcParamsDefault.copy()`, the fontsize won't decrease to the original value. Also after having tried this reset, even with `plt.rcParams.update()` I can't decrease the fontsize anymore. I am using PyCharm, but this behavior appears even in a plain IPython console.

Is Python accessing a another, "hidden", set of parameters? Should I change plot parameters differently?

Specifications: Python 3.7.6, matplotlib 3.1.2, IPython 7.11.1

Consider this minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()

np.random.seed(999)
data = np.random.random((10,10))

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(data)

plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 30})

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(data)

bug = False
if bug:
    plt.rcParams = plt.rcParamsDefault.copy()
    plt.ion()
else:
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 10})

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(data)
```

Comment: Please do not use a construct like `plt.rcParams = plt.rcParamsDefault.copy()`, since it will not actually update the parameters. You may use `plt.rcdefaults()` to restore the original parameters, or update the dictionary, like `plt.rcParams.update(plt.rcParamsDefault)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll use those expressions from now on :)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it only appears as if it had updated the parameters when you read the dictionary keys, but in reality it has not done so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options to restore the default parameters:

- `plt.rcdefaults()` (as mentionned in [@ilke444's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60523330/4124317))
- or update the dictionary, like `plt.rcParams.update(plt.rcParamsDefault)`

---

> So why does `plt.rcParams = plt.rcParamsDefault.copy()` not work?

This is because you simply assign some new dictionary to a variable. It will not update the original one. To understand this condsider a simple case

```
mydict = dict(a=5, b=5)

class Usage():
    def __init__(self, dic):
        self.dic = dic

    def do_something(self):
        print(self.dic)

usage = Usage(mydict)
usage.do_something()
# prints {'a': 5, 'b': 5}

mydict.update({"a" : 0})
usage.do_something()   
# prints {'a': 0, 'b': 5}

mydict = dict(a=2, b=2)
usage.do_something()   
# still prints {'a': 0, 'b': 5}, because only the variable
# mydict is changed, but how should `usage` know about that change?
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [rcParams documentation](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#matplotlibrc-sample):

1. Changing current context parameters are done like below, not via `plt.rcParams.update()` function.

`plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 10`

2. Restoring the matplotlib defaults (or the `matplotlibrc` file defaults) are done like below.

`plt.rcdefaults() # from matplotlib defaults`

`plt.rc_file_defaults() # from file`

Can you try with these update and reset functions? My suspicion is that the update function may be rewriting the current or file defaults. I also remember reading rcParams behaving differently in the IPython console, but I can't find the reference right now.

Comment: ad (1): I guess both should work reasonably (as I understand it, the `update()` does the same); ad (2): `plt.rcdefaults()` works. It however makes me wonder, why the dictionary copy does not...